# tar exclude folders ignored when called from bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar

The following code didn't work, exclude folders are ignored by tar. How can I fix that ? Please note I may have multiple exclude folders and multiple folders to backup.

```
date=`date +%Y%m%d`

# tar_create function
# ARG1=<filename_to_write> ARG2=<exclusions> ARG3=<folders>
tar_create () {
    exclude_options=()
    if [ ${#exclude[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
        for x in "${2[@]}"; do
            exclude_options+=(--exclude="$x")
        done
    fi
    echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S'): Running tar czvpf "${1}" "${exclude_options[@]}" ${@:3}"
    tar czvpf "${1}" "${exclude_options[@]}" ${@:3} 2>&1 > "${1}.txt"
    ret=$?
    if [ $ret != 0 ] && [ $ret != 1 ]; then
        echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S'): Error: tar returned $ret for ${1}"
        echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S'): Error: tar returned $ret for ${1}" >> "${1}-errors.txt"
    fi
    echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S'): End tar czvpf "${1}" "${exclude_options[@]}" ${@:3} : return $ret"
}

# do_backup function
# ARG1=<filename_to_write> ARG2=<root folder to backup> ARG3=<exclusions in tar format> ARG4=<folders to backup>
do_backup () {
    if [ ! -d "$(dirname "${1}")" ] || [ ! -w "$(dirname "${1}")" ]; then
        echo "Folder ${1} doesn't exist or isn't writable, can't write backup files" >> backup-error.log
    fi
    if [ ! -d "$(dirname "${2}")" ]; then
        echo "Folder to backup ${1} doesn't exist" >> backup-error.log
    fi

    declare -a exclude=("${!3}")
    declare -a folders=("${!4}")
    declare -a all=("${exclude[@]}" "${folders[@]}")

    echo "cd ${2}"
    cd "${2}"
    echo "tar_create ${1} ${3} ${4}"
    tar_create "${1}" "${3}" "${4}"
}
exclude=( './photos' './videos' './archives' )
folders=( './' )
do_backup "/hdd/backup-$date.tar.gz" "/home/datastorez" "${exclude[@]}" "${folders[@]}"
```

Comment: If the tar paths are absolute, the excludes have to be absolute.  If the paths are relative, i.e. ".", then the excludes must be of the form "./{pattern}".

Comment: Should you have the "**!**" in the lines ... **declare -a exclude=("${!3}")** ...and ... **declare -a folders=("${!4}")** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal example how you could use a function to create the tar file.
In your code it's not possible to distinguish the exclusions and the backup folders when passed
to the function as arguments. Arrays are expanded to multiple words using the `"${name[@]}"` syntax.

Example: If the `exclude` array is empty, argument `$3` in `do_backup` would be the first element
of `folders`. If there are two items in the `exclude` array, then the first element of `folders` would be `$5`.

Changes:

- `$1`: name of the backup
- `$2`: directory to switch to
- `$3`: name of the `excludes` array variable. In the function we declare a variable using
  the `nameref` attribute (`-n`) to access the array elements.
- `$4`-`$n`: directories to backup

```
# ARG1=<filename_to_write> ARG2=<change_to_dir> ARG3=<name_of_exclude_array> ARG4...=<directories>
tar_create () {
    local -n excl=$3
    local exclude_options=()
    for i in "${excl[@]}"; do
        exclude_options+=( --exclude "$i" )
    done

    tar czvpf "$1" -C "$2" "${exclude_options[@]}" "${@:4}"
}

exclude=( ./photos ./videos ./archives )
dirs=( ./ )
tar_create /hdd/backup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz /home/datastorez exclude "${dirs[@]}"
```